# I install nagois, not showing up on localhost/nagois

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nagios

I installed nagois on ubuntu.  The service is running as nagois3.  I am trying to access it via the browser as localhost/nagois/, its giving me a 404.

Any ideas.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You say "nagois" Are you sure you don't mean "Nagios" the monitoring tool ?

Comment: ummm... sorry probably slip of my fingers.  Yes its a monitoring tool

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly installed everything Nagios needs ?

Nagios needs:

- Apache 2
- PHP
- GCC compiler and development libraries
- GD development libraries

A good resource for installing Nagios on Ubuntu can be found [HERE](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart-ubuntu.html) , did you go trough all those steps ?

Comment: Do you get anything if you open localhost or 127.0.0.1 in your browser?